# Using a dynamic variable with threads in Java

Tags: java, thread-sleep, jslider

I have a thread `z` that is created when a certain JButton `begin` is clicked. Inside the run method of that thread, I need to include a dynamic variable `val` which changes its value periodically. `Val` has been declared globally.
 This change is modeled correctly by the `stateChanged` function of a JSlider, which continues to print out the correct value for `val` in the console. However, in my `run` method, the variable `val` does not change as needed. It stays constant as the initial value when the Thread was created.

Here are my functions below:

```
int val;
Thread z;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource().equals(step)) {
        simulation();
    }

    else if (e.getSource().equals(begin)) {
        if (running==false) {
            running = true;
            z = new Thread(this);
            z.start();
        }
    }

    else if (e.getSource().equals(end)) {
        running = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    val = slider.getValue();
    System.out.println(val);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (running==true) {
        simulation();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(val+200); //SHOULD BE DYNAMIC
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Any thoughts on how I can change the variable `val` to be dynamic would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the complete class where `val` is declared ?

Comment: It's simply declared in the constructor method. Just updated...

Comment: It sounds like the problem is not that it is not "dynamic" (altered during thread execution by `stateChanged(ChangeEvent)`). I would bet you have two instances of this class, one run in a new Thread and another that the JSlider updates. Could you share how you're creating and starting the thread? Also, that `val` variable is not really "global." If you made it `static` then you could consider it global, as in class-level.

Comment: The thread is also declared in the main constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `val` is NOT `volatile` so whenever the `main` `Thread` updates the variable the `runnable()` `Thread` is NOT able to view it.

Similarly ensure that you are marking `running` variable (used inside `while` loop) as `volatile`, otherwise the `runnable()` thread will run forever (without receiving the update from the other thread).

> What is volatile? What does it mean?

In simple words, marking a variable as `volatile` makes the writes of one thread visible to the other threads. This is required because when a thread is writing to a variable, the variable data is cached (local to the thread) and it might NOT be visible to the other threads, until the writing thread flushes the data. So `volatile` ensures that the data is not cached rather it is always written/fetched from main memory.

I suggest yo to understand the basics of thread communication by referring [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).

Comment: What is `volatile`? What does it mean?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: This worked perfectly! However, it also worked (as I posted below) if I changed val to `static`. Why is this? Is there a difference?

Comment: `static` does not guarantee the writes of thread, just it makes that it is a class level variable, where as `volatile` ensures the thread writes are visible across as explained above